# Клиент серверное приложение - Аутентификация

Tags: rest, retrofit

Есть  API сайта. Пока есть регистрация и авторизация. Использую Retrofit для запросов.
Помогите пожалуйста понять, после авторизации что и где хранить , чтобы при повторном запуске приложения мне не приходилось заново логиниться. Вот например авторизовался. То , что я получаю от сервера response().headers() - это Set-cookie identity. Я должен именно с ним работать?  Я должен хранить у себя в prefs это поле , и при каждом запуске проверять это поле с тем ,что приходит от сервера? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Самое простое, что можно придумать - сохранить логин и пароль в приложении и отсылать эти сохранённые данные каждый раз для входа

Comment: Мне надо с сессиями и куками работать